# String tokenization strange character output

Tags: c, token

I am trying to tokenize an array of strings, however, my program keeps printing these strange characters. I believe it has something to do with null-terminating my string. If that is the problem then what can I do to fix it?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* s[] = { "12, 34, 56, 78", "82.16, 41.296",
                  "2, -3, 5, -7, 11, -13, 17, -19",
                  "9.00009, 90.0009, 900.009, 9000.09, 90000.9" };

    char *token = strtok(s, ", ");

    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a photo of the output.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: see warning. fix like [this](http://ideone.com/f320eY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have either messed up your declaration of `s` (most likely given the remainder of you code), or your have messed up how you declare `s` and call strtok on `s` (which is an *array-of-pointers-to-char** containing pointers to *string literals*, as written.)

It appears you actually want `char s[]` as your declaration. Which would reveal problems with several *missing* **and** several *extraneous* `','`s in the initialization. To declare `s` as an *array-of-char* initialized holding the list of *comma-separated-values*, you essentially want

```
char s[] = { "12, 34, 56, 78, ....,  9000.09, 90000.9" };
```

There is no requirement that you have only one set of quotes (`".."`) in the initialization, but each value you seek to tokenize from the string must have a *comma* that follows (except for the last value). You could declare and initialize `s` as follows:

```
char s[] = { "12, 34, 56, 78," "82.16, 41.296,"
              "2, -3, 5, -7, 11, -13, 17, -19,"
              "9.00009, 90.0009, 900.009, 9000.09, 90000.9" };
```

The remainder of your code works fine in that case, producing the following output:

```
$ ./bin/strtok_arr
12
34
56
78
82.16
41.296
2
-3
5
-7
11
-13
17
-19
9.00009
90.0009
900.009
9000.09
90000.9
```

If your intent was to create an *array-of-pointers-to-char** (e.g. `char *s[]`), then you must rework the declaration and the remainder of your code, because (1) you are not passing a character pointer to `strtok`; and (2) `strtok` modifies the string it is passed making a call to `strtok` while passing a *string literal* just plain wrong -- and guaranteed to *SegFault*.

Let me know if you have any questions.

---

**As an array-of-pointers-to-char***

From your comment, if you need to find the *mean* or *average* of each of the individual strings within `s`, then `s` must be *an array-of-pointers-to-char**. As explained in the comment, you cannot initialize `char *s[]` to contain `{ "stuff", "morestuff", ... }` because `"stuff"` and `"morestuff"` are *string literals* and in most cases will be created in *read only* memory. Since `strtok` modifies the original string, you will be attempting to modify *read-only* memory, which 9 times out of 10 results in a friendly *segmentation fault* (not good).

You can however simply create the individual strings as *character arrays* and then create `s` from the character arrays, e.g.:

```
    char s1[] = "12, 34, 56, 78",
         s2[] = "82.16, 41.296",
         s3[] = "2, -3, 5, -7, 11, -13, 17, -19",
         s4[] = "9.00009, 90.0009, 900.009, 9000.09, 90000.9",
         *s[] = { s1, s2, s3, s4 };
```

You can then finish your code by tokenizing each of the strings with `strtok` and converting each value to `double` while collecting the `sum` and `average` of each. e.g.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char s1[] = "12, 34, 56, 78",
         s2[] = "82.16, 41.296",
         s3[] = "2, -3, 5, -7, 11, -13, 17, -19",
         s4[] = "9.00009, 90.0009, 900.009, 9000.09, 90000.9",
         *s[] = { s1, s2, s3, s4 };
    size_t i, idx = 0, n = sizeof s/sizeof *s;
    double avg[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        double sum = 0.0;
        size_t nval = 0;
        char *token = strtok (s[i], ", ");

        while (token != NULL) {
            sum += strtod (token, NULL);
            nval++;
            printf ("  %8s, sum : %9.2lf\n", token, sum);
            token = strtok (NULL, ", ");
        }
        printf ("----------------------------\n");
        printf ("        average : %9.2lf\n\n", (avg[idx++] = sum/nval));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would probably rewrite the tokenization loop as a `for` loop to include the `nval` increment in the loop definition itself, e.g.

```
        for (; token; token = strtok (NULL, ", "), nval++) {
            sum += strtod (token, NULL);
            printf ("  %8s, sum : %9.2lf\n", token, sum);
        }
```

In either case, your `sum` and `average` of each string will look like the following:

```
$  ./bin/strtok_arr1
        12, sum :     12.00
        34, sum :     46.00
        56, sum :    102.00
        78, sum :    180.00
----------------------------
        average :     45.00

     82.16, sum :     82.16
    41.296, sum :    123.46
----------------------------
        average :     61.73

         2, sum :      2.00
        -3, sum :     -1.00
         5, sum :      4.00
        -7, sum :     -3.00
        11, sum :      8.00
       -13, sum :     -5.00
        17, sum :     12.00
       -19, sum :     -7.00
----------------------------
        average :     -0.88

   9.00009, sum :      9.00
   90.0009, sum :     99.00
   900.009, sum :    999.01
   9000.09, sum :   9999.10
   90000.9, sum : 100000.00
----------------------------
        average :  20000.00
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: That worked great and it prints like it should. I am trying to write a program that then takes those tokenized strings, converts them to doubles and then finds the mean of each row. In my instructor's solution, he uses char* = s[..] and separates each string within the array with a comma; so that's why I thought I needed to do that as well. I'm still not sure why he did that or how he made it work though. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: If you need the mean for each *row*, and you consider a *row* to be, e.g. `"12, 34, 56, 78"`, then you *will* need `char *s[]` so that you can pass each row to `strtok` or `strsep`. However, you cannot declare `s` the way you originally did because `"stuff"` contained *within* `{ "stuff", "morestuff", ...}` are *string literals* created in *read-only* memory of the `.rodata` section (Linux). Since `strtok` and `strsep` modify the original string, passing a read-only string to `strtok` will cause a *segmentation fault* or (`segfault`). I'll work an alternative, also see *cdlane's* answer.

Comment: Your edit helped a lot! Thank you for your help and your time.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok()` takes a pointer to a character array (which I'll call a "string" here), but you are passing it an *array of strings*.

Furthermore, `strtok()` *modifies* the string you pass in by replacing delimiters with null characters.

The array of strings that you are passing to `strtok()` consists of pointers to the individual strings in the array. So the garbled display is the result of these pointers being displayed as strings. Furthermore, when `strtok()` modifies the "string" you give it, this can result in all sorts of memory corruption.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to anticipate the two problems BLUEPIXY has with Nuchy's solution, the following code copies the constant strings into user allocated memory so that they can be modified sans a BUS ERROR on Unix.

The below uses the newer, reentrant `strsep()` instead of `strtok()`.

The `", "`, if passed to `strsep()`, unlike the original code, doesn't break at, and remove, the combination of comma and space, it breaks at both.  But just using `","` leaves an unwanted space on the data, which I remove separately.

Finally, I reformated the data to make it clear that there are four input strings, not three, and computed the number of strings instead of hard coding the count:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE (1024)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char strings[][BUFFER_SIZE] = {
        "12, 34, 56, 78",
        "82.16, 41.296",
        "2, -3, 5, -7, 11, -13, 17, -19",
        "9.00009, 90.0009, 900.009, 9000.09, 90000.9"
    };

    size_t limit = sizeof(strings) / BUFFER_SIZE;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        char *token, *string = strings[i];

        while ((token = strsep(&string, ",")) != NULL) {
            while (isspace(*token)) {
                token++;
            }
            printf("%s\n", token);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hah! You even protect against an empty field by using `strsep`, good job. However, if I were a wagering man, (which I'm not), I would be willing to wager, that given the additional complexity required to handle the *array of pointers to char\**, the OP probably has his problem in the declaration of `s` rather than in the remainder of his code. But that is just an educated guess `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I guess I should have taken that wager!

Comment: Yep, I would be digging in my pockets to pay up `:)` (that's a prime example of why I'm not a betting man in things containing uncertainty I cannot control).

Answer (score 0):

You need to tokenise each string individually - the strtok() function accepts a pointer to a char as its first argument:

```
char *strtok(char * str, const char * delim);
```

Something like:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* s[] = { "12, 34, 56, 78", "82.16, 41.296",
                  "2, -3, 5, -7, 11, -13, 17, -19",
                  "9.00009, 90.0009, 900.009, 9000.09, 90000.9" };
    int sNo = 0;

    while (sNo < 4) {
        char *token = strtok(s[sNo++], ", ");

        while (token != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ", ");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This, of course - requires that you know the size of the array in advance.

Comment: this has two problem.

Comment: Why 4 when there are 3 entries in `s`?  Also, you are modifying string literals, which is certainly going to give your code headaches if you ever move to a Unix-based machine where the literals live in readonly memory.

Comment: There are 4 separate strings in s. you are right, though - strtok modifies the input string and this will cause problems.